# Using Google Sheets conditional formatting to highlight a cell based upon range in a single column

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a GSheet that I use to track resources.  Column A are the names of the participants, column E has a pull-down list of roles that each participant will be assigned.  Column J has a list of the roles and as a participant is assigned a particular role, I'd like that role in Column J to have it's background changed to green.  This provides and easy way to confirm that I've assigned all roles.

I've searched all over the place, tried various examples, but the best I can do is get the role to highlight based upon a single cell in column E, but not the entire column.

So for the role of Computer Operator (Cell J9) if I use the custom formula of: =E2="Computer Operator" then J9 will turn green when I select Computer Operator in E2.  But if I change the formula to =E2:E50="Computer Operator" to cover those 2-50 in column E, J9 immediately turns back to a white background and regardless of what I select in column E, it will not change back to green.

[Column E Example showing all roles that can be selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59PFc.png)

[Column J Example showing the "Display" of selected Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM4qY.png)

Basically as each role is selected in E, the corresponding Role is lit green in J.  If the role is unselected in E, then it goes back to white in J.  It's merely an easy way to look to see if all roles have been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. Since it is not feasible for Apps Script to check in real time which cell is selected, a [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) with an IF condition would work better.
In this example, I added the formula to Column K, next to each role of the Column J. 
In my example, the roles go from J1 to J9.

So from K1 to K9 I set the formula:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(J1, E1:E,1,FALSE) = J1, "OK")
```

Of course, each row with it's respective J. I hope this helps, as VLOOKUP is much faster than running a script.

Comment: Ok, Fairly certain I follow your logic.  However, since I have multiple roles to check for in column J, if I understand correctly, an edit in that column would light the field green regardless of the value.  I currently have 9 roles to check for.

Comment: No, only an edit in column E would trigger the script. For example, if you write `Computer Operator` in E7, it would highlight the same value in Column J.

Comment: Right, but if I go to E8 and select Proctor, the script will trigger and color all cells on which it's applied to turn green.  I want to detect what is selected and color that cell green.  I'm not sure how to do a screen shot, but perhaps that would help convey what I'm wanting to do.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now, so what you mean is you _only_ want to color a single role, and if you select another one, the new will be green and the old will be white again? If you are using Windows, you can use the `Snipping Tool` and post the screenshots in your original post.

Comment: I've edited to add two snips from the gsheet.  See if that helps.  I've also added a bit more to the explanation.

Comment: It's not possible to run a script when a Cell is active unless it's edited. I changed my answer, as I think using formulas will be better.